# Blackberry push plugin create error

Tags: cordova, push-notification, blackberry-10

I am using the Phonegap Push Plugin for Blackberry and have got all the credentials from Blackberry Push Service. I'm trying to test this stuff in debug but I always get this error.

```
Error: An internal error occurred while calling blackberry.push.PushService.create. Try restarting the application.
```

Unfortunately it doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Any chance you could post the output from the web inspector console?

Comment: Its really just that, after I call register that appears in the console.